# Maximum notation of Euclidean distance

Tags: notation

Can someone explain to me what does the max mean? Why there is an i below the max? Thank you.
$$
 \mathop { \max }\limits_i \left\lVert \mathbf a_i\right\rVert_2
$$

Comment: There is not enough information in your post to say conclusively. I would guess whoever wrote that has defined a family of vectors $\{a_i \mid i \in I\}$ and is talking about the maximum over all vectors from that family.

Comment: So it's referring to the vector with the largest Euclidean distance?

Comment: $a_i$ is just a vector

Comment: It could be the $i-th$ component of a vector with Euclidean Distance.